# Sorting string array with custom-formatted date

Tags: blackberry-jde

I have a string like

```
String str[]={"jan2011","feb2011","jan2010,"mar2012"};
```

How do I sort this by Date like: jan2010,jan2011,feb2011,mar2012

thanks for advance(not to use string functions more )

Comment: thank u i correct  it once again look it

Answer (score 0):

Hoi:

```
String[] unsorted={"jan2011","feb2011","jan2010","mar2012"};
List<String> unsortedList = Arrays.asList(unsorted);
Collections.sort(unsortedList);
String[] sorted = (String[])unsortedList.toArray();
```

This should do...

Comment: @gruber that will sort alphabetically, not by date

Comment: thank u fnd but i am developing a blackberry application so here collections not working

Comment: @govind I'm a bit confused now, what exactly are you looking for?  a sort function in Java?

Comment: your code is not working in java also because if in string array all strings either strings or numbers then it is working but in my string it is not working

Comment: @fvu sir actully java collection functions working in if string array contain  all strings either strings or numbers  but i need short above string array plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have [version 6](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/com/google/zxing/common/Collections.html) at your disposal, you can use the built-in

```
Collections.insertionSort(datavector, comparator);
```

However:

- you'll need to move your strings into a [Vector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/index.html?com/google/zxing/common/Collections.html)
- you'll need to provide a Comparator class for your specific needs

The Comparator class could be something along these lines:

```
public class DatestringComparator implements Comparator{

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        // create Date instance based on the content of the input string
        Date d1 = ....; 
        Date d2 = ....;
        return d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u sir, but i did not get this plz provide me code for my requirement